# create a temp table with the output of a stored procedure in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, function, stored-procedures

I want a query to create a table with the output of a stored procedure function in Postgres.

**SQL:**

`CREATE TEMP TABLE new_project AS select project_insert('1','test2343','tew3234','ccc',1);`

**Error:**

```
ERROR:  42P16: column "projects_insert" has pseudo-type record
LOCATION:  CheckAttributeType, heap.c:513
```

**Note:** `project_insert` is a function which insert the values and returns inserted values

Comment: Sorry, its not working

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `project_insert` has been declared with `RETURNS record`, and that type is illegal for a column definition.

You have to specify name and type of the result columns in the query, like this:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE new_project AS
   SELECT x, y, z
   FROM project_insert('1','test2343','tew3234','ccc',1)
        AS p(x integer, y text, z bytea);
```

Replace the names and types with the appropriate names and types.

See [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-TABLEFUNCTIONS) for details.